# Allow User to Change Background Colour in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, colors

I want to be able to change the colour of the background when a specific button is clicked on, e.g. btnRed changes the background colour to red. I am able to change the background to blue, but I can't get the other colours working, and I want to be able to do this with multiple colours. Could this be done with just HTML and JavaScript? I have provided my code below. I appreciate the help.

HTML

```
<button class="btnBlue">Blue</button>
<button class="btnRed">Red</button>
<button class="btnGreen">Green</button>
<button class="btnOrange">Orange</button>
<button class="btnYellow">Yellow</button>
<button class="btnPink">Pink</button>
<button class="btnPurple">Purple</button>
<button class="btnBrown">Brown</button>
<button class="btnBlack">Black</button>
<button class="btnGray">Gray</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");    
var isBlue = false;

button.addEventListener("click",function()
    {
        if(isBlue)
        {
            document.body.style.background = "white";
            isBlue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.body.style.background = "blue";
            isBlue = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: If I've understood your "question" correctly, you have a button for each background color, and now you want to know how you make all those buttons to change the bgcolor?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the bg color whenever I click on a button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the texts of the buttons as colors.

NB: I would give all those buttons the same class attribute, so you can easily select them all

```js
const colorButtons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.colorButton')];
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (!colorButtons.includes(e.target)) return;
    document.body.style.background = e.target.textContent;
});
```

```html
<button class="colorButton">Blue</button>
<button class="colorButton">Red</button>
<button class="colorButton">Green</button>
<button class="colorButton">Orange</button>
<button class="colorButton">Yellow</button>
<button class="colorButton">Pink</button>
<button class="colorButton">Purple</button>
<button class="colorButton">Brown</button>
<button class="colorButton">Black</button>
<button class="colorButton">Gray</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by:

HTML:

```
<button class="btnBlue"     onclick="changeColor('blue')">Blue</button>
<button class="btnRed"      onclick="changeColor('red')">Red</button>
<button class="btnGreen"    onclick="changeColor('green')">Green</button>
<button class="btnOrange"   onclick="changeColor('orange')">Orange</button>
<button class="btnYellow"   onclick="changeColor('yellow')">Yellow</button>
<button class="btnPink"     onclick="changeColor('pink')">Pink</button>
<button class="btnPurple"   onclick="changeColor('purple')">Purple</button>
<button class="btnBrown"    onclick="changeColor('brown')">Brown</button>
<button class="btnBlack"    onclick="changeColor('black')">Black</button>
<button class="btnGray"     onclick="changeColor('gray')">Gray</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeColor(colorName) {
    document.body.style.background = colorName;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know if the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This would work perfectly

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background color</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

See reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp

Comment: I'll try this later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to do styling changes with with CSS rather than as inline styling or with javascript - the following simply grabs the text of the button you click and applies that as a class name to the body. Each of the classes has associated styling to apply when it is selected.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button"); 
var body = document.querySelector("body"); 

buttons.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener("click",function(){
  var color = this.textContent.toLowerCase();
  body.className= color;
 });
})
```

```css
.blue {background-color: blue}
.red {background-color: red}
.green {background-color: green}
.orange {background-color: orange}
.yellow {background-color: yellow}
.pink {background-color: pink}
.purple {background-color: purple}
.brown {background-color: brown}
.black {background-color: black}
.gray {background-color: gray}
```

```html
<button class="btnBlue">Blue</button>
<button class="btnRed">Red</button>
<button class="btnGreen">Green</button>
<button class="btnOrange">Orange</button>
<button class="btnYellow">Yellow</button>
<button class="btnPink">Pink</button>
<button class="btnPurple">Purple</button>
<button class="btnBrown">Brown</button>
<button class="btnBlack">Black</button>
<button class="btnGray">Gray</button>
```